# Rendering Product in Shopify Blog Post Article using card-product.liquid

Tags: css, shopify, rendering, liquid

I'm trying to show products card inside blog posts / articles of shopify.
I've edited main-article.liquid so that when the content of an article is rendered, it checks the content for a particular string and then splits the code.
if a split has occurred than it isolates the handle of the product.

then it will need to render the product based on the product handle as a card-product.
card-product is the element in which a product is show in a collection ( as in a catalog list )

though I cannot render the product but just a dummy element as in this [image: picture]

I've followed 2 tutorials to get this far:
[happypoint](https://happypoints.io/blog/shopify-add-products-to-blog-post-c2-stt-66/#:%7E:text=From%20your%20Shopify%20admin%2C%20go%20to%20Products%20%3E%20All%20products.,Copy%20the%20product%20handle.)
[thefunction](https://thefunction.works/how-to-add-product-blocks-inside-your-blog-using-nothing-but-liquid-shopify/)

the first one is using a snippet that is not present in my theme ( dawn ) but also adding it just to se some results brings out same missing content problem but in a different design.

```
    {%- when 'content'-%}
          <div class="article-template__content page-width page-width--narrow rte" itemprop="articleBody" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>

             {% assign divider = '[PROD]' %}
    {% assign dividerClose = '[/PROD]' %}
    {% assign text = article.content | split: divider %} 

    {{ text[0] }}

    {% for divider in text offset:1 %}
     {% assign x = forloop.index %}
    {% assign newtext = text[x] | split: dividerClose %}
    {% assign productHandle = newtext[0] %}                        
    {% assign product = all_products[productHandle] %}  
     <div class="product_item">
                       {% render 'card-product',
                  
                    media_aspect_ratio: section.settings.image_ratio,
                    show_secondary_image: section.settings.show_secondary_image,
                    show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor,
                    show_rating: section.settings.show_rating,
                    lazy_load: lazy_load,
                    show_quick_add: section.settings.enable_quick_add,
                    section_id: section.id

                  %}
                     </div>
    {{ newtext[1] }}

    {% endfor %}

            
          </div>
```

How can I render the product as a card-product.liquid?

Comment: where you pass the `product` into `render`, I think you missed it.

Comment: I've tested out with a correct handle in the body of the article and an incorrect one. 
when the correct handle is found it renders the example result as in first post.
when the incorrect handle is used, then nothing is rendered.

Thank you Onkar, I'm not sure how to pass the product into the render. and I thought that was the way. How should I pass the product into render?